# Joining two queries that have INNER JOINS in them

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm trying to join these two SQL queries together. My data is at https://policevideorequests.cartodb.com/tables/seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails which has a Postgresql SQL API.

```
SELECT 
    t1.customer_id, t1.c,
    t2.customer_name, t2.customer_email, t2.customer_email_domain 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         a.customer_id, count(a.customer_id) as c 
     FROM 
         (SELECT customer_id, reference_no 
          FROM seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails 
          WHERE customer_id NOT IN (5, 0, -1) 
          GROUP BY customer_id, reference_no) a 
     GROUP BY 
         a.customer_id 
     ORDER BY 
         count(a.customer_id) DESC) t1 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         customer_id,
         INITCAP(LOWER(SUBSTRING(new_value FROM 'Dear&nbsp;(.*?):</div>'))) as customer_name,
         LOWER(SUBSTRING(new_value FROM 'login:<b>(.*?)</b>')) as customer_email, 
         LOWER(SUBSTRING(new_value FROM 'login:<b>.*?@(.*?)</b>')) as customer_email_domain 
     FROM 
         seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails 
     WHERE 
         SUBSTRING(new_value FROM 'Dear&nbsp;(.*?):</div>') IS NOT NULL) t2 ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id 
ORDER BY 
    t1.c DESC

SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.new_value as requester_type, t2.customer_id 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         reference_no, new_value 
     FROM 
         seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails 
     WHERE 
         action_desc = 154) t1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         reference_no, customer_id 
     FROM 
         seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails 
     WHERE 
         customer_id NOT IN (0, -1, 5)) t2 ON t1.reference_no = t2.reference_no
```

My attempt at joining the two:

```
SELECT t1.customer_id,t3.requester_typer,t1.c,t2.customer_name,t2.customer_email,t2.customer_email_domain,t2.customer_email_domain_tld FROM (SELECT a.customer_id,count(a.customer_id) as c FROM (SELECT customer_id, reference_no FROM seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails WHERE customer_id NOT IN (5,0,-1) GROUP BY customer_id,reference_no) a GROUP BY a.customer_id ORDER BY count(a.customer_id) DESC) t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT customer_id,INITCAP(LOWER(SUBSTRING(new_value FROM 'Dear&nbsp;(.*?):</div>'))) as customer_name,LOWER(SUBSTRING(new_value FROM 'login:<b>(.*?)</b>')) as customer_email, LOWER(SUBSTRING(new_value FROM 'login:<b>.*?@(.*?)</b>')) as customer_email_domain, LOWER(SUBSTRING(new_value FROM 'login:<b>.*?@.*?\.(.*?)</b>')) as customer_email_domain_tld FROM seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails WHERE SUBSTRING(new_value FROM 'Dear&nbsp;(.*?):</div>') IS NOT NULL) t2 
ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id ORDER BY t1.c DESC
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT t1.new_value as requester_type,t2.customer_id FROM (SELECT reference_no,new_value FROM seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails WHERE action_desc = 154) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT reference_no,customer_id FROM seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails WHERE customer_id NOT IN (0,-1,5)) t2
ON t1.reference_no = t2.reference_no) as t3
ON t2.customer_id = t3.customer_id
```

I get the error "syntax error near INNER"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your SQL query is that you tried to keep `ORDER BY` in the middle. The `ORDER BY` clause must be moved all the way to the back of the query, because ordering is applied to the entire query, not to its parts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  SELECT t1.customer_id,t3.requester_typer,t1.c,t2.customer_name,t2.customer_email,t2.customer_email_domain,t2.customer_email_domain_tld FROM (SELECT a.customer_id,count(a.customer_id) as c FROM (SELECT customer_id, reference_no FROM seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails WHERE customer_id NOT IN (5,0,-1) GROUP BY customer_id,reference_no) a GROUP BY a.customer_id ORDER BY count(a.customer_id) DESC) t1 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT customer_id,INITCAP(LOWER(SUBSTRING(new_value FROM 'Dear&nbsp;(.*?):</div>'))) as customer_name,LOWER(SUBSTRING(new_value FROM 'login:<b>(.*?)</b>')) as customer_email, LOWER(SUBSTRING(new_value FROM 'login:<b>.*?@(.*?)</b>')) as customer_email_domain, LOWER(SUBSTRING(new_value FROM 'login:<b>.*?@.*?\.(.*?)</b>')) as customer_email_domain_tld FROM seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails WHERE SUBSTRING(new_value FROM 'Dear&nbsp;(.*?):</div>') IS NOT NULL) t2 
    ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT t1.new_value as requester_type,t2.customer_id FROM (SELECT reference_no,new_value FROM seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails WHERE action_desc = 154) t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT reference_no,customer_id FROM seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails WHERE customer_id NOT IN (0,-1,5)) t2
    ON t1.reference_no = t2.reference_no) as t3
    ON t2.customer_id = t3.customer_id
    ORDER BY t1.c DESC
```